# R: remove/drop multi-collinear variables, based on a output of multi-collinearity test output

Tags: r, variable-selection

I have a dataset of 32 variables and 48 observations (observations would increase, as we are in the phase of data collection thru subscriptions). 
Since the dataset has high multicollinearity, I introduced Farrar – Glauber Test. The individual measure (idiags) of the test has a parameter called Klein which has values 0s and 1s, saying whether the variables multi-collinearity or not.
Now based on the values of Klien I need to remove the columns from the main dataset. I'm stuck on how to remove/drop from main dataset(model_df), based on Klein values in the dataset imcdiag_idiagval.

My sample code below,
model_df0 : dataset without target variable 
model_df:   dataset with target variable

```
library(mctest)

#Farrar – Glauber test(F–test) for location of multicollinearity
# Individual Multicollinearity Diagnostic Measures
imcdiag_out = imcdiag(model_df0, model_df$TARGET)
summary(imcdiag_out)
#Output of summary function below,
        Length Class  Mode   
idiags   224   -none- numeric
x       1536   -none- numeric
y         48   -none- numeric
method     0   -none- NULL   
corr       1   -none- logical
call       3   -none- call   
pval      29   -none- numeric
R2         1   -none- numeric
all        1   -none- logical
alldiag  224   -none- logical

imcdiag_idiagval = as.data.frame(imcdiag_out$idiags)

> imcdiag_idiagval$Klein
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Out of the 32 variables, the values with 1s in Klein has multi-collinearity. Hence need to remove them

```
> dput(head(model_df))
structure(list(Mon = structure(c(2014.33333333333, 2014.41666666667, 
2014.5, 2014.58333333333, 2014.66666666667, 2014.75), class = "yearmon"), 
    Al_Prod_Qty = c(4516084.63333333, 4488436.58064516, 4529767.5, 
    4468792.16129032, 4515652.4516129, 4513669.13333333), US_Indus_Growth = c(2.72933333333333, 
    3.00806451612903, 3.25466666666667, 3.41161290322581, 4.03322580645161, 
    3.22333333333333), China_Elec_Rail = c(6.206, 7.30733333333333, 
    7.18741935483871, 5.84322580645161, 3.90166666666667, 5.65290322580645
    ), DS_Index = c(80.4, 79.81, 81.52, 82.78, 86.05, 87.02), 
    Al_Prod_Africa = c(152L, 143L, 144L, 148L, 142L, 144L), Al_Prod_NorthAmerica = c(392L, 
    372L, 386L, 386L, 372L, 379L), Al_Prod_SouthAmerica = c(135L, 
    117L, 117L, 116L, 111L, 120L), Al_Prod_AsiaEXChina = c(203L, 
    193L, 203L, 198L, 194L, 204L), Al_Prod_WestEurope = c(304L, 
    297L, 306L, 306L, 298L, 307L), Al_Prod_EastCentralEurope = c(319L, 
    309L, 319L, 319L, 310L, 321L), Al_Prod_Oceania = c(178L, 
    174L, 175L, 166L, 160L, 165L), Al_Prod_GCC = c(418L, 412L, 
    427L, 426L, 413L, 426L), Al_Prod_ChinaEstimated = c(12, 15, 
    18, 22, 23, 24), Al_Prod_Total = c(4441L, 4419L, 4507L, 4553L, 
    4502L, 4619L), Al_Prod_DailyAvg = c(143.3, 147.3, 145.4, 
    146.9, 150.1, 149), almna_prod_AfricaAsiaExChina = c(395L, 
    445L, 459L, 436L, 413L, 395L), almna_prod_NorthAmerica = c(440L, 
    444L, 479L, 476L, 441L, 455L), almna_prod_SouthAmerica = c(1137L, 
    1077L, 1047L, 1063L, 1068L, 1097L), almna_prod_WestEurope = c(326L, 
    363L, 334L, 386L, 351L, 323L), almna_prod_EastCentralEurope = c(352L, 
    322L, 330L, 321L, 325L, 325L), almna_prod_Oceania = c(1696L, 
    1632L, 1663L, 1631L, 1579L, 1693L), almna_prod_ChinaEstimated = c(4513L, 
    4448L, 4509L, 4461L, 4416L, 4754L), almna_prod_Total = c(8859L, 
    8731L, 8821L, 8774L, 8593L, 9042L), almna_prod_DailyAverage = c(285.77, 
    291.03, 284.55, 283.03, 286.43, 291.68), TARGET = c(1749.1, 
    1834.4, 1945.41, 2030.23, 1992.48, 1938.2), lme_al_3month_price = c(1790.98, 
    1868.83, 1967.28, 2038.1, 2023.48, 1956.39), lme_al_stock = c(5271645, 
    5116815, 4990208, 4887148, 4706865, 4519988), Coal_Central_Appalachia_Price = c(60.7, 
    60.05, 57.25, 56.35, 54.59, 56.3), Coal_Northern_Apppalachia_Price = c(65.5, 
    64.5, 63.7, 62.75, 63.3, 65.55), Coal_Illinois_Basin_Price = c(46, 
    45.45, 44, 44, 43.4, 44.7), Coal_Powder_River_Price = c(13, 
    12.55, 12.25, 11.55, 11.25, 11.55), Coal_Uinta_Basin_Price = c(36.75, 
    36.75, 36.45, 36.45, 37, 37.75), BrentCrudePrice = c(109.21, 
    111.03, 104.94, 101.12, 94.67, 84.17)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000025f1ef0>)
```

Comment: Try model_df0[!imcdiag_idiagval$Klein] or model_df[!imcdiag_idiagval$Klein]

Comment: Its not removing the columns/variables

Comment: @Arun May be you need to restart your RStudio. BTW what's output of `model_df[!imcdiag_idiagval$Klein] `?

Comment: restarted Rstudio as well as R. But its discarding only the first row/observation. Whereas the variables remains the same

Comment: @Arun Perhaps you are using a `,` after `!imcdiag_idiagval$Klein` otherwise it should keep rows intact.  May be you can share output of `dput(head(model_df))` as part of question.

Comment: Im not using "," after !imcdiag_idiagval$Klein, as it would implement in rows

Comment: comments section is not able to paste the entire answer from 'dput', out of some 50 lines, it allows only upto 5 lines.

Comment: @Arun I had suggested to put it as part of question itself.

Answer (score 0):

If 1 indicates the variable is not multi-collinear, flow code:

```
#raw data

dataset<-sapply(paste0("var",1:32), function(x) assign(x,rnorm(n=48)) )

imcdiag_idiagval.Klein<-c(0 ,0 ,0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0 ,0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1, 1, 1 ,1 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 

#final data without multi-collinearity

final_dataset<-dataset[,imcdiag_idiagval.Klein==1]
```

### Edit post to work with your data set.

In your data you have 34 columns:

```
names(data) 
 [1] "Mon"                             "Al_Prod_Qty"                    
  [3] "US_Indus_Growth"                 "China_Elec_Rail"                
  [5] "DS_Index"                        "Al_Prod_Africa"                 
  [7] "Al_Prod_NorthAmerica"            "Al_Prod_SouthAmerica"           
  [9] "Al_Prod_AsiaEXChina"             "Al_Prod_WestEurope"             
 [11] "Al_Prod_EastCentralEurope"       "Al_Prod_Oceania"                
 [13] "Al_Prod_GCC"                     "Al_Prod_ChinaEstimated"         
 [15] "Al_Prod_Total"                   "Al_Prod_DailyAvg"               
 [17] "almna_prod_AfricaAsiaExChina"    "almna_prod_NorthAmerica"        
 [19] "almna_prod_SouthAmerica"         "almna_prod_WestEurope"          
 [21] "almna_prod_EastCentralEurope"    "almna_prod_Oceania"             
 [23] "almna_prod_ChinaEstimated"       "almna_prod_Total"               
 [25] "almna_prod_DailyAverage"         "TARGET"                         
 [27] "lme_al_3month_price"             "lme_al_stock"                   
 [29] "Coal_Central_Appalachia_Price"   "Coal_Northern_Apppalachia_Price"
 [31] "Coal_Illinois_Basin_Price"       "Coal_Powder_River_Price"        
 [33] "Coal_Uinta_Basin_Price"          "BrentCrudePrice"
```

So you need a vector of 33:

```
 imcdiag_idiagval.Klein<-sample(0:1,33,replace = T)
```

Add response variaable:

```
fina_index<-c(imcdiag_idiagval.Klein,1)
```

Final data:

```
final_data<-data[,fina_index==1]
```

Compare:

```
dim(final_data)[2]
[1]  6 16
sum(fina_index)
[1] 16
sum(fina_index)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually these commands should work. I have tried this. But its resulting only a logical vector as below,                       > final_dataset<-model_df[,imcdiag_idiagval$Klein==1]
> head(final_dataset)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

Comment: final_dataset<-model_df[,c(imcdiag_idiagval$Klein,1)==1]

Comment: > class(imcdiag_idiagval$Klein)
[1] "numeric"
> final_dataset<-model_df[,c(imcdiag_idiagval$Klein,1)==1]
> head(final_dataset)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

Comment: Is it possible to post your data?

Comment: If its my personal data, I could have. Since its official data, I'm not supposed to. Thanks for understanding

Comment: > dim(model_df0)
[1] 48 32
> imcdiag_out = imcdiag(model_df0, model_df$TARGET)
> imcdiag_idiagval = as.data.frame(imcdiag_out$idiags)
> imcdiag_idiagval.Klein<-sample(0:1,32,replace = T)
> fina_index<-c(imcdiag_idiagval.Klein,1)
> final_data<-model_df[,fina_index==1]
> dim(final_data)[2]
NULL
> dim(final_data)
NULL
> head(final_data)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

Comment: please report `dim(model_df)[2]-dim(model_df0)[2]`.

Comment: > dim(model_df)[2]-dim(model_df0)[2]
[1] 2                           ( its the Month and TARGET variable, which creates the difference

Comment: so 
 `final_dataset<-model_df[,c(1,imcdiag_idiagval$Klein,1)==1]`

Comment: Still no luck.            > final_dataset<-model_df[,c(1,imcdiag_idiagval$Klein,1)==1]
> final_dataset
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[12] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[23]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[34]  TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where 1 means a column should be dropped from the data frame, using the `mtcars` sample data.

```
data(mtcars)

# set up true false variable where 1 = drop, 0 = keep
# noting that it is of type numeric(), not logical()
drop <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)

# this will result in a data frame that
# contains 7 columns, excluding drat, wt, qsec, and vs

theSubset <- mtcars[!drop]
head(theSubset)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(theSubset)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105  0    3    1
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the results. Actually these commands should work. I have tried this. But its removing only the row, not the variables that is not needed. Seems for my scenario, its something unique. Not sure where the issue is

Comment: Hmm...  Is it possible that `model_df` is not a data frame? what happens when you run `str(model_df)` from the R console?

Comment: model_df is a dataframe. All the variables in it are integer class, except 'Mon', which is 'yearmon'